# Changing background of layout null pointer exception

Tags: android, arrays, drawable

I am trying to alternate the background image of a linear layout via a random array of drawables  but keep getting a null pointer exception:

```
Integer[] images = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawanle.image2};
Random whichImage = new Random();
Int theImage= whichImage.nextInt(1);

View myView= findViewById(R.layout.splash);
myView.setBackgroundResource
(imageSelection[theImage]);
setContentView(myView);
```

The null pointer occurs at `myView.setBackground`.....

Cheers.....

Comment: Does `imageSelection` get initialized? I see that the array you are using for the image id's is called images ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an int to a background resource.

Instead of

```
myView.setBackgroundResource(imageSelection[theImage]);
```

try

```
myView.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(imageSelection[theImage]));
```

Comment: 1) The method is not applicable for getResources. 2)It doesn't work

Comment: Stop saying "it doesn't work" to everyone! Probably, in your particuilar case, you have to prepend a context (passed as a parameter or native to the Activity) to getResources, depending on your code.

Comment: @Aerox Do you think a fellow member with 11k rep will write a gibberish code? There are many solutions for a given problem, depending on your code. Any single solution isn't a universal code applicable to all the coding problems in the world. You even wrote "It doesn't work" to the OP's answer!! He would have provided his answer after resolving the problem, wouldn't he? Either explain yourself or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Integer[] images =    
{R.drawable.image1,R.drawanle.image2};
```

with this

```
int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.image1,R.drawanle.image2};
```

Comment: @Aerox Simply writing it doesn't work won't help anyone, either explain what doesn't work or ask your own question.

Comment: @Aerox We are not here to give bad code. And it's obvious that a given code could not work under particular conditions. Ask your own question to get a customized solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer[] images =     {R.drawable.image1,R.drawanle.image2};
Random whichImage = new Random();

Int theImage= whichImage.nextInt(1);

setContentView(R.Layout.splash);
View myView= findViewById(R.id.view);

myView.setBackgroundResource (imageSelection[theImage]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Should this
Int theImage= whichImage.nextInt(1);
// be replaced with
Int theImage= whichImage.nextInt(images.length);

//Then move your setBackgroundResource call to after you call the setContentView method.  
setContentView(myView);
myView.setBackgroundResource(image[theImage]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, there was something wrong with my View myView ref, I think this was returning null. When I used the to get the background it worked fine:

```
this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(imageSelection[theImage]);
```